# Como faço para centralizar os links de uma navbar visualizada em mobiles com bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, css3, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3

Seguinte, estou usando a versão do bootstrap 3.7.2 para fazer uma navbar e configurei-a para que, quando "colapsada", ou seja, qdo visualizamos em dispositivos mobile, ela fica com o botão toggle na direita e a logo fica localizada à esquerda devido a configurações css. Até aí tudo bem, mas qdo clicado, os links aparecem com um alinhamento à esquerda. Que configuração eu posso usar para alinhar esses links ao centro desse "dropdown" criado pelo bootstrap somente nessa visualização?
Segue o código da navbar:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-default navbar-fundo"> <!-- Barra de Navegação -->

        <div class="container-fluid"> <!-- Agrupar logo toggle e links -->

            <div class="navbar-header">

                <!-- Botão Alternar -->
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed navbar-right" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#barra-navegacao" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Alternar navegação</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

                <!-- Logo Carta -->
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
                    <span class="img-logo">Logo</span>
                </a>
            </div> <!--/navbar-header-->

            <!-- navbar -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="barra-navegacao">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active font_nav">
                        <a href="index.html">
                            Home
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="font_nav">
                        <a href="relatos.html">
                            Relatos
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="font_nav">
                        <a href="escreva.html">
                            Escreva seu relato
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="font_nav">
                        <a href="info.html">
                            Informações
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="font_nav">
                        <a href="privacidade.html">
                            Privacidade
                        </a>
                    </li>                   
                </ul>

            </div> <!--/itens da barra-navegacao-->


        </div> <!--/nav container-fluid-->

    </nav>
```

Outra coisa menos importante: tem como fazer o link que está ativo no momento apareça ao centro da navbar como se fosse o título da página?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adicione a classe `text-center` na `ul navbar-nav`.

**Veja:**

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-default navbar-fundo"> <!-- Barra de Navegação -->

        <div class="container-fluid"> <!-- Agrupar logo toggle e links -->

            <div class="navbar-header">

                <!-- Botão Alternar -->
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed navbar-right" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#barra-navegacao" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Alternar navegação</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

                <!-- Logo Carta -->
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
                    <span class="img-logo">Logo</span>
                </a>
            </div> <!--/navbar-header-->

            <!-- navbar -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="barra-navegacao">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav text-center">
                    <li class="active font_nav">
                        <a href="index.html">
                            Home
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="font_nav">
                        <a href="relatos.html">
                            Relatos
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="font_nav">
                        <a href="escreva.html">
                            Escreva seu relato
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="font_nav">
                        <a href="info.html">
                            Informações
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="font_nav">
                        <a href="privacidade.html">
                            Privacidade
                        </a>
                    </li>                   
                </ul>

            </div> <!--/itens da barra-navegacao-->


        </div> <!--/nav container-fluid-->

    </nav>
```

Comment: É só usar a classe nativa do BS `text-center` na UL, `<ul class="nav navbar-nav text-center">` []´s

Comment: Melhor ainda :D valeu!

Comment: Agora sim! tmj!